# Accidentally input c_rehash cmd in folder

Tags: java, c, linux, bash, shell

I just imput the following cmd in a folder: c_rehash

I think that all my child directories got affected, they contain java, c files.
Since this mistake i cannot compile c files anymore and when i use the classic gcc cmd: gcc -o file.c file

my file.c disapear.

I would like to know if this cmd is reversable, im currently a computer science student and i need help fast.

Thanks.

[c_rehash input folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8bJl.png)

[error when i try compile c program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIHAJ.png)

[tree vision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPC30.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `c_rehash`. Your issue is that you're telling GCC to make an output file named `min_max_moy.c` from an input file named `min_max_moy`. It does just that, then encounters an error because `min_max_moy` is not a valid input file. As a result, your `.c` file is deleted.

The `-o` option must be followed by the name of the output file, not the input file. So you should call GCC like this instead:

```sh
gcc -o min_max_moy min_max_moy.c
```

or:

```sh
gcc min_max_moy.c -o min_max_moy
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i was convinced that it was c_rehash fault that i didn't even checked the integrity of my command. I'm sorry i wasted your time on such a dumb question.